# Regular representation of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is indecomposable but not irreducible

Tags: representation-theory

I am familiar with the analogous example when $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_2$. The $\mathbb{F}_2\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{F}_2\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ contains four elements, and the action of $g \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $g\begin{pmatrix} a \\b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b \\a \end{pmatrix}$, which implies the only proper subrepresentation is  $\text{span}_{\mathbb{F}_2}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, hence $\mathbb{F}_2\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is reducible but indecomposable, since there is only one submodule we can non-trivially $\oplus$ by.

---

Now when upscale to $\mathbb{F}_3\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, things get hazy. How many elements are there in $\mathbb{F}_3\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}=\text{span}_{\mathbb{F}_3}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$? I believe the action of $g \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is $g\begin{pmatrix} a \\b \\c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} c \\a \\b \end{pmatrix}$, correct? If so I can find the associated (permutation) matrices. Likewise to the above, is the only proper subrepresentation $\text{span}_{\mathbb{F}_3}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$? How would I argue this? I know they are $G$-stable subspaces.

I have seen related questions which invoke linear algebra facts, but I want to work this out by strictly abstract algebra means.

Comment: The zero sum subspace is another (2-dimensional) subrepresentation containing the 1-dimensional that you found. Those turn out to be the only ones, though. But the problem is that the 1-dimensional submodule you found has no complementary submodule.

Comment: Thank you, I have some more information now: I know the module I found is the trace submodule $N$ which is the *unique* 1-D submodule of $\mathbb{F}G$, and the module you mentioned is the augmentation ideal $I$, a 2-D submodule. It is clear to me why $N \subseteq I$, and why we cannot $\oplus$ $I$ with itself $3$ times to get $\mathbb{F}G$. But it is not clear to me why $I$ is the only codimension $1$ submodule of $\mathbb{F}G$ -- as you say these "turn out to be the only ones." Why is that?

Comment: Let's do the following. Assume that there is a submodule $V$ such that $N\oplus V=\Bbb{F}G$. This means that we can write the neutral element of the group algebra as a sum $$1=n+v$$ with $n\in N$ and $v\in V$. Multiplying that equation with $s=1+g+g^2$ leads to the following problem. On the left hand sides you get $s$. But  we observe that the element $s$ annihilates $N$. Basically because $s^2=0$ in the group algebra. So we get
$$s=sn+sv=sv\in V.$$ As $s\in N$ this violates the assumption that $N$ and $V$ intersect trivially.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\\alpha \\\alpha \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\\alpha_2 \\\alpha_3 \end{pmatrix}$ implies $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=-\alpha$. So the second vector summand is in $N$, contradiction.

Comment: Wait, $1$ is the element $(1,0,0)^T$. You need the multiplication by $s$, I think. The point is if you multiply $(1,0,0)^T$ with $s$ you get $s=(1,1,1)^T$ back. But on the right the first term is all zeros, and this leads to a contradiction. If you dig further into the theory, then it is revealed that the element $s$ belongs to the (Jacobson) radical of the group algebra.

Comment: Ah, yes I see! Thank you for correcting.